# Flutter debugging build will not load the assets on ios device

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter

When I run the flutter gallery on iOS iPhone X, the assets are missing. I'm using the master channel.

I was able to get the gallery running on iPhone 8 plus and then after running it again it did the same thing. When loading the assets won't load.

I'm not sure what's failing yet. I'm guessing the builds cache needs to be cleaned so it will copy the assets. Reseting the simulator won't work for me.

Do you have any idea how to fix the debug build for iOS?

What it looks like:
[image]

The exception that occurs on loading the application.

```
Unable to load asset: AssetManifest.json
#0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:221:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      CachingAssetBundle._fetchString (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:160:33)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      CachingAssetBundle.loadString (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:156:12)
#3      CachingAssetBundle.loadStructuredData (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:184:5)
#4      AssetImage.obtainKey (package:flutter/src/services/image_resolution.dart:167:18)
#5      ImageProvider.resolve (package:flutter/src/services/image_provider.dart:264:5)
#6      _ImageState._resolveImage (package:flutter/src/widgets/image.dart:468:33)
#7      _ImageState.didChangeDependencies (package:flutter/src/widgets/image.dart:449:5)
#8      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3688:12)
#9      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widg<…>
```

Here is the doctor output:

```
Brandons-MacBook-Pro:flutter_gallery branflake2267$ flutter doctor
[✓] Flutter (on Mac OS X 10.13 17A405, locale en-US, channel master)
    • Flutter at /Users/branflake2267/git/flutter
    • Framework revision acdbe45670 (14 hours ago), 2017-10-27 18:23:50 -0700
    • Engine revision ec19da1c80
    • Tools Dart version 1.25.0-dev.11.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 26.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/branflake2267/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-26, build-tools 26.0.2
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version openjdk version "1.8.0_152-release"

[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 9.0.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 9.0.1, Build version 9A1004
    • ios-deploy 1.9.2
    • CocoaPods version 1.3.1

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.0)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio 3.0.app/Contents
    • Java version openjdk version "1.8.0_152-release"

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.0)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Java version openjdk version "1.8.0_152-release"

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2017.2.5)
    • Flutter plugin version 18.1
    • Dart plugin version 172.4155.35

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2017.2.5)
    • Flutter plugin version 17.0
    • Dart plugin version 172.4155.35

[✓] Connected devices
    • Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554                        • android-x86 • Android 8.0.0 (API 26) (emulator)
    • iPhone X                  • 4CDF751B-C49B-46A4-A120-231AAF47C958 • ios         • iOS 11.0 (simulator)
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue as well last night after I upgraded my `master` branch. My temporary fix: Revert from the `master` to the `alpha` branch.

I've also filed a github issue here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/12776

Comment: That's the first thing I do before debugging is run an upgrade and there hasn't been any new patches that have fixed it yet. I have noticed that I can run it on a new simulator and it works. But at some point it regresses back to missing assets

Answer (score 0):

Following steps helped me

1. Quit the app
2. Clean the project, `>> flutter clean`
3. Run the app, `>> flutter run`